# NoClassDefFoundError in Android Plugin for Unity

Tags: java, android, plugins, unity-game-engine

I'm working on Android Plugin for my Unity game. My plugin should return GCM token for my application. 
My gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "testproject.com.pushtoken"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
            //resources {
            //    srcDir 'libs'
            //}
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile files('libs/classes.jar')
}

task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'libs/pluginLibrary7.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('plugins/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'pluginLibrary7.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

Plugin contains simple methods for testing its capability ( like return int value) and of course it has the method for getting gcm token. The problem is when I try to launch the method in order to receive gcm token, I get this error:

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID
```

I understand that the problem is my .jar library doesn't have gms library. But how should I include it to my .jar file?

Comment: Comment out `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line for testing case

Comment: Thank you for your response, IntelliJ! Already tried, same situation :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I figured out the problem. The reason of this error was that my library wasn't packaged properly. I mean library seemed like it had all needed external libraries, but when I opened the .jar file to see what's inside, I'd found out that it has just folders for external libraries, which were totally empty.

My fix was very simple. I opened my .jar library and put necessary external libraries there with my hands. After that I've made the new .jar from updated package and it works.

I have couple of recommendations for people who would choose my way of fixing this problem. I'm using Macbook in my work, and I've had hard time with editing .jar file, because whenever I made new .jar file by standard utilities, it didn't work with Unity. So I used WinRAR on my second Windows PC for making the .jar and after that all things started to work.

I hope my tips will be helpful for somebody. P.S.: Sorry for my poor English.